# jQuery tabs enable horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

How to enable ***horizontal scrolling*** on jQuery tabs within a specific width on a ***single line***.

By default, jQuery UI plugin moves the last tab on next line.

So, I've been using a workaround to increase the width by a bit by setting the css style as below,

```
#tabs_div .scroller {
  overflow: auto;
}
#tabs_div ul { 
  width: 1100px; 
}
```

And tabs are set as below,

```
<div id='tabs_outer_div' class="tabs">
  <div id='tabs_div' class="scroller" style='display:none;width:100%'>
   <ul>....
 </div>
</div>
```

Edited to include jsfiddle, here the tabs are shown in multiple rows. How to set them in one single row (line). - http://jsfiddle.net/karthikn_jay/pdnr0op9/

Comment: Can you share a Live fiddle..! it helps us see your work and shoot the issue easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add Custom style in your style sheet to `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav` and `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li` if need add parent level unique `selector`

http://jsfiddle.net/pdnr0op9/3/ `like this`